# Find multiple integrals $I_{\max}(k,n)$ and $I_{\min}(k,n)$ in various ways

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, big-list

1. $I_{\max}(k,n)=\underbrace{\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1\dots\int\limits_0^1}_k\left(\max\limits_{1\le i\le k}x_i\right)^n\,dx_1dx_2\dots dx_k$
2. $I_{\min}(k,n)=\underbrace{\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1\dots\int\limits_0^1}_k\left(\min\limits_{1\le i\le k}x_i\right)^n\,dx_1dx_2\dots dx_k$

Various solutions are welcome.

P.S. I added my solution as an answer.

Comment: What solutions do you already know?

Comment: @dfeuer I know solution which uses the fact that $*(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)=*(*(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n-1}),x_n)$ (where $*$ is $\max$ or $\min$). Then it is possible to divide $I_{*}(k,n)$ into two integrals which are expressed using $I_{*}(k-1,\cdot)$. So it is recurrence relation.

Comment: Constructor, you should post that as an answer here to get the list started.

Comment: @dfeuer OK, I'll write it.

Comment: Sorry, what does $\max^n$ mean?

Comment: @Bennett Gardiner $\max^n(\cdot)=\left(\max(\cdot)\right)^n$

Comment: @dfeuer I added my solution as an answer, you can see it.

Comment: @BennettGardiner I changed using notation, I hope it became more clear.

Answer (score 3):

1) Evaluation of $I_{\max}(k,n)$

It is clear that $\max x = x$ so $I_{\max}(1,n)=\int\limits_0^1 x_1^n\,dx_1=\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Also it is obvious that $\max\limits_{1\le i\le k}x_i=\max\left(x_k,\max\limits_{1\le i\le k-1}x_i\right)$. Then

$$\begin{align}I_{\max}(k,n)&=\underbrace{\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1\dots\int\limits_0^1}_k\left(\max\left(x_k,\max\limits_{1\le i\le k-1}x_i\right)\right)^n\,dx_1dx_2\dots dx_k=\\
&=\underbrace{\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1\dots\int\limits_0^1}_{k-1}\left(\int\limits_0^{\large\max\limits_{1\le i\le k-1}x_i}\left(\max\limits_{1\le i\le k-1}x_i\right)^n \,dx_k+\int\limits_{\large\max\limits_{1\le i\le k-1}x_i}^1 x_k^n \,dx_k\right)\,dx_1dx_2\dots dx_{k-1}=\\
&=\underbrace{\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1\dots\int\limits_0^1}_{k-1}\left(\left.\left(\max\limits_{1\le i\le k-1}x_i\right)^n x_k\right|_0^{\large\max\limits_{1\le i\le k-1}x_i}+ \left.\frac{x_k^{n+1}}{n+1}\right|_{\large\max\limits_{1\le i\le k-1}x_i}^1\right)\,dx_1dx_2\dots dx_{k-1}=\\
&=\underbrace{\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1\dots\int\limits_0^1}_{k-1}\left(\left(\max\limits_{1\le i\le k-1}x_i\right)^{n+1} +\frac{1-\left(\max\limits_{1\le i\le k-1}x_i\right)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right) \,dx_1dx_2\dots dx_{k-1}=\\
&=\frac{1}{n+1}\cdot\left(n\underbrace{\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1\dots\int\limits_0^1}_{k-1}\left(\max\limits_{1\le i\le k-1}x_i\right)^{n+1}\, dx_1dx_2\dots dx_{k-1}+1\right)=\\
&=\frac{1}{n+1}\cdot\left(nI_{\max}(k-1,n+1)+1\right)\end{align}$$
By induction it can be shown that $I_{\max}(k,n)=\frac{k}{k+n}$:

- $\left.I_{\max}(k,n)\right|_{k=1}=\frac{1}{1+n}=\frac{1}{n+1}$
- $I_{\max}(k+1,n)=\frac{1}{n+1}\cdot\left(nI_{\max}(k,n+1)+1\right)=\frac{1}{n+1}\cdot\left(n\cdot\frac{k}{k+(n+1)}+1\right)=\frac{nk+k+n+1}{(n+1)(k+n+1)}=\\=\frac{(n+1)(k+1)}{(n+1)(k+n+1)}=\frac{k+1}{(k+1)+n}$

2) Evaluation of $I_{\min}(k,n)$

It is clear that $I_{\min}(1,n)=\int\limits_0^1 x_1^n\,dx_1=\frac{1}{n+1}$. We will find $I_{\min}(k,n)$ in the same manner as we did it for $I_{\max}(k,n)$:

$$\begin{align}I_{\min}(k,n)&=\underbrace{\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1\dots\int\limits_0^1}_k\left(\min\left(x_k,\min\limits_{1\le i\le k-1}x_i\right)\right)^n\,dx_1dx_2\dots dx_k=\\
&=\underbrace{\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1\dots\int\limits_0^1}_{k-1}\left(\int\limits_0^{\large\min\limits_{1\le i\le k-1}x_i} x_k^n \,dx_k+\int\limits_{\large\min\limits_{1\le i\le k-1}x_i}^1 \left(\min\limits_{1\le i\le k-1}x_i\right)^n \,dx_k\right)\,dx_1dx_2\dots dx_{k-1}=\\
&=\underbrace{\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1\dots\int\limits_0^1}_{k-1}\left(\left.\frac{x_k^{n+1}}{n+1}\right|_0^{\large\min\limits_{1\le i\le k-1}x_i}+ \left.\left(\min\limits_{1\le i\le k-1}x_i\right)^n x_k\right|_{\large\min\limits_{1\le i\le k-1}x_i}^1\right)\,dx_1dx_2\dots dx_{k-1}=\\
&=\underbrace{\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^1\dots\int\limits_0^1}_{k-1}\left(\left(\min\limits_{1\le i\le k-1}x_i\right)^n-\frac{n}{n+1}\cdot\left(\min\limits_{1\le i\le k-1}x_i\right)^{n+1}\right) \,dx_1dx_2\dots dx_{k-1}=\\
&=I_{\min}(k-1,n)-\frac{n}{n+1}\cdot I_{\min}(k-1,n+1)\end{align}$$

By induction it can be shown that $I_{\min}(k,n)=\frac{k!n!}{(k+n)!}=\binom{k+n}{k}^{-1}$:

- $\left.I_{\min}(k,n)\right|_{k=1}=\frac{1!n!}{(1+n)!}=\frac{1}{n+1}$
- $I_{\min}(k+1,n)=I_{\min}(k,n)-\frac{n}{n+1}\cdot I_{\min}(k,n+1)=\frac{k!n!}{(k+n)!}-\frac{n}{n+1}\cdot\frac{k!(n+1)!}{(k+(n+1))!}=\\=\frac{k!n!}{(k+n+1)!}\cdot((k+n+1)-n)=\frac{(k+1)!n!}{((k+1)+n)!}$

Answer (score 3):

Denote by $C$ the part of the unit cube $[0,1]^k$ where $\max_{1\leq i\leq k}x_i=x_k$. The plane $x_k=x$ intersects $C$ in the set $$C_x=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_{k-1})\,|\,0\leq x_i\leq x \ (1\leq i\leq k-1)\}$$ of volume $x^{k-1}$. By Fubini's theorem we therefore obtain
$$I_\max(k,n)=k\int_C x^n {\rm d}(x_1,\ldots, x_{k-1},x)=k \int_0^1x^n\>x^{k-1}\>dx={k\over n+k}\ .$$
Similarly, denote by  $D$ the part of $[0,1]^k$ where $\min_{1\leq i\leq k}x_i=x_k$.  Then $$D_x:=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_{k-1})\,|\,x\leq x_i\leq 1 \ (1\leq i\leq k-1)\}$$ has volume $(1-x)^{k-1}$. By Fubini's theorem we therefore obtain
$$I_\min(k,n)=k\int_D x^n {\rm d}(x_1,\ldots, x_{k-1},x)=k \int_0^1x^n\>(1-x)^{k-1}\>dx= {n+k\choose k}^{-1}\ .$$

Comment: $\binom{n}{k}^{-1}$? Not $\binom{n+k}{k}^{-1}$?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I have rechecked the output of Mathematica and corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

To show another approach, consider that in general we can write
$$
\eqalign{
  & I(f,A) = \int\limits_{(x_{\,1} , \cdots ,x_{\,k} )\, \in \,A} {f(x_{\,1} , \cdots ,x_{\,k} )\,dx_{\,1}  \cdots dx_{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \int\limits_{{\bf x}\, \in \,A} {f({\bf x})\,dA}  = 
 \int\limits_{{\bf x}\, \in \,A} {\left( {\int\limits_{z = 0}^{f({\bf x})} {dz} } \right)\,dA} \quad \left| {\;f: \mathbb R^{\,k}  \to \mathbb R} \right. \cr} 
$$
that means that $I(f,A)$  , in the space $(\bf x, z)$, is the
volume comprised between the plane $z=0$ and the surface $z=f(\bf x)$, 
and inside the cylinder ${{\bf x}\, \in \,A}$.

When $0 \le f(\bf x)$ in all the integration domain,  we can compute the volume by integrating over the cross sections $A(z)dz$, intending by
A(z) the "area" (measure) of the domain in which  $z < f({\bf x})$, i.e.
$$
A(z) = \mu \left( {{\bf x}\, \in \,A:f({\bf x}) = z} \right)
$$
so
$$
\eqalign{
  & I(f,A) = \int\limits_{(x_{\,1} , \cdots ,x_{\,k} )\, \in \,A} {f(x_{\,1} , \cdots ,x_{\,k} )\,dx_{\,1}  \cdots dx_{\,k} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \int\limits_{z = 0}^{\max \left( {f({\bf x})} \right)} {A(z)dz}  \cr} 
$$

Coming to our case, we have 
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le x_{\,j}  \le 1\quad \left| {\;j \in \left\{ {1, \cdots ,k} \right\}} \right. \hfill \cr 
  \left[ {z < \min (x_{\,1} , \cdots ,x_{\,k} )^{\,n} } \right]\;\mathop  = \limits^{0\, \ne \,n} \;\left[ {z^{\,1/n}  < \min (x_{\,1} , \cdots ,x_{\,k} )} \right] =  \hfill \cr 
   = \left( {\left[ {z^{\,1/n}  < x_{\,1}  \le 1} \right] \cdots \left[ {z^{\,1/n}  < x_{\,k}  \le 1} \right]} \right)\;\quad  \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad A_{\,\min } (z) = \left[ {0 \le z \le 1} \right]\left\{ {\matrix{
   1 & {0 = n}  \cr 
   {\left( {1 - z^{\,1/n} } \right)^{\,\,k} } & {0\, \ne \,n}  \cr 
 } } \right. \cr} 
$$
and
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le x_{\,j}  \le 1\quad \left| {\;j \in \left\{ {1, \cdots ,k} \right\}} \right. \hfill \cr 
  \left[ {z < \max (x_{\,1} , \cdots ,x_{\,k} )^{\,n} } \right]\;\mathop  = \limits^{0\, \ne \,n} \;1 - \left[ {\max (x_{\,1} , \cdots ,x_{\,k} ) \le z^{\,1/n} } \right] =  \hfill \cr 
   = 1 - \left[ {0 \le x_{\,1}  \le z^{\,1/n} } \right] \cdots \left[ {0 \le x_{\,k}  \le z^{\,1/n} } \right] \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad A_{\,\max } (z) = \left[ {0 \le z \le 1} \right]\left\{ {\matrix{
   1 & {0 = n}  \cr 
   {\left( {1 - z^{\,\,k/n} } \right)} & {0\, \ne \,n}  \cr 
 } } \right. \cr} 
$$
where $[P]$ denotes the [*Iverson bracket*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)
$$
\left[ P \right] = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   1 & {P = TRUE}  \\
   0 & {P = FALSE}  \\
 \end{array} } \right.
$$

Therefore
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & I_{\,\min } (k,n) = \int_0^1 {A_{\,\min } (z)dz}  = \int_0^1 {\left( {1 - z^{\,1/n} } \right)^{\,\,k} dz}  =   \cr 
  &  = n\int_0^1 {\left( {1 - t} \right)^{\,\,k} t^{\,\,n - 1} dt}  = nB(k + 1,n) = {{\Gamma (k + 1)\Gamma (n + 1)} \over {\Gamma (n + k + 1)}} = {1 \over {\left( \matrix{
  n + k \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}} \cr} 
} $$
and
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
I_{\,\max } (k,n) = \int_0^1 {A_{\,\max } (z)dz}  = \int_0^1 {\left( {1 - z^{\,\,k/n} } \right)dz}  = {k \over {k + n}}
} $$

Note that the method can be  applied to  integration
bounds different from $0 \cdots 1$, and  to real 
 values of $n$ (and also of $k$ ..)